# How to convert a byte array to its numeric value (Java)?

Tags: java, algorithm, arrays, numbers

I have an 8 byte array and I want to convert it to its corresponding numeric value.

e.g.

```
byte[] by = new byte[8];  // the byte array is stored in 'by'

// CONVERSION OPERATION
// return the numeric value
```

I want a method that will perform the above conversion operation.

Comment: What do you mean by "numeric value"? Do the bytes represent an integer (long) or floating point number (double) in binary?  Are they the string representation of a number?  Or yet another representation?

Comment: This was helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399798/byte-array-and-int-conversion-in-java

Comment: NB: TacB0sS' link was what I was actually looking for- both forwards and backwards conversion.

Comment: `new BigInteger(by).longValue()`

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Assuming the first byte is the least significant byte:

```
long value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < by.length; i++)
{
   value += ((long) by[i] & 0xffL) << (8 * i);
}
```

Is the first byte the most significant, then it is a little bit different:

```
long value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < by.length; i++)
{
   value = (value << 8) + (by[i] & 0xff);
}
```

Replace long with [BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), if you have more than 8 bytes.

Thanks to Aaron Digulla for the correction of my errors.

Comment: -1 bytes are signed values! And replace pow() with shift (<<)! "value = (value << 8) + (by[i] & 0xff)"

Comment: Does the shift operator(<<) has right to left precedence? How does above code works? Its working all fine for me. Just wanna know the working. Thanx in advance

Comment: @Mnementh : Does the shift operator(<<) has right to left precedence? How does above code works? Its working all fine for me. Just wanna know the working. Thanx in advance

Comment: In case anyone else has the same issue I did, in the first example, by[i] must be cast to a long, otherwise it only works for values less than 2^32.  That is, `value += ((long)by[i] & 0xffL) << (8 * i);`

Answer (score 124):

One could use the [`Buffer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html)s that are provided as part of the [`java.nio`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) package to perform the conversion.

Here, the source `byte[]` array has a of length 8, which is the size that corresponds with a `long` value.

First, the `byte[]` array is wrapped in a [`ByteBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), and then the [`ByteBuffer.getLong`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getLong()) method is called to obtain the `long` value:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4});
long l = bb.getLong();

System.out.println(l);
```

Result

```
4
```

I'd like to thank dfa for pointing out the `ByteBuffer.getLong` method in the comments.

---

Although it may not be applicable in this situation, the beauty of the `Buffer`s come with looking at an array with multiple values.

For example, if we had a 8 byte array, and we wanted to view it as two `int` values, we could wrap the `byte[]` array in an `ByteBuffer`, which is viewed as a [`IntBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html) and obtain the values by [`IntBuffer.get`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#get(int)):

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4});
IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();
int i0 = ib.get(0);
int i1 = ib.get(1);

System.out.println(i0);
System.out.println(i1);
```

Result:

```
1
4
```

Comment: what about ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4}).getLong()? this method should read next 8 byte and convert them to a long

Answer (score 17):

If this is an 8-bytes numeric value, you can try:

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(byteArray);
```

If this is an UTF-8 character buffer, then you can try:

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(new String(byteArray, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I would've voted for this answer if it ended right after the first code snippet, or if it included some code to convert the string into a "numeric value". As-is, the second half of your answer seems like a non sequitur.

Comment: Not what I meant in the first place, I changed my answer

Answer (score 17):

Simply, you could use or refer to *guava* lib provided by google, which offers utiliy methods for conversion between long and byte array. My client code:

```
    long content = 212000607777l;
    byte[] numberByte = Longs.toByteArray(content);
    logger.info(Longs.fromByteArray(numberByte));
```

Comment: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html

Answer (score 9):

You can also use BigInteger for variable length bytes. You can convert it to Long, Integer or Short, whichever suits your needs.

```
new BigInteger(bytes).intValue();
```

or to denote polarity:

```
new BigInteger(1, bytes).intValue();
```

Answer (score 4):

Complete java converter code for all primitive types to/from arrays
http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216874.html

Answer (score 1):

Each cell in the array is treated as unsigned int:

```
private int unsignedIntFromByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
int res = 0;
if (bytes == null)
    return res;


for (int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++){
    res = res | ((bytes[i] & 0xff) << i*8);
}
return res;
}
```

Comment: Just a note that I needed to use 0xFFL, otherwise the cast from int 0xFF to long had a whole lot of incorrect 1 bits set when I printed Long.toHexString(l).

Comment: You need to use 0xFFL otherwise you get sign extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long byteArrayToLong(byte[] bytes) {
    return ((long) (bytes[0]) << 56)
            + (((long) bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 48)
            + ((long) (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 40)
            + ((long) (bytes[3] & 0xFF) << 32)
            + ((long) (bytes[4] & 0xFF) << 24)
            + ((bytes[5] & 0xFF) << 16)
            + ((bytes[6] & 0xFF) << 8)
            + (bytes[7] & 0xFF);
}
```

convert bytes array (long is 8 bytes) to long

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68393576/7918717

It parses bytes as a signed number of **arbitrary** length. A few examples:

`bytesToSignedNumber(false, 0xF1, 0x01, 0x04)` returns `15794436` (3 bytes as *int*)

`bytesToSignedNumber(false, 0xF1, 0x01, 0x01, 0x04)` returns `-251592444` (4 bytes as *int*)

`bytesToSignedNumber(false, 0xF1, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x04)` returns `-1080581331768770303` (8 of 9 bytes as *long*)