# How to convert a Java Long to byte[] for Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra

Lazy programmer alert.  :)

Cassandra stores column values as bytes ([Java example](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples#Java)).  Specifying a [LongType comparator](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration#line-67) compares those bytes as a long. I want the value of a long into a Cassandra-friendly byte[].  How?  I poked around for awhile.  I think you people can help me faster.

**EDIT:**

Both Alexander and Eli's answers agreed with [this reverse transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586882/how-do-i-convert-a-byte-to-a-long-in-java/1586920#1586920). Thanks!

Comment: Okay, you're just picky. That's ok, even admirable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is cut and paste from java 6 `DataOutputStream.writeLong`

```
public final void writeLong(long v) throws IOException {
    writeBuffer[0] = (byte)(v >>> 56);
    writeBuffer[1] = (byte)(v >>> 48);
    writeBuffer[2] = (byte)(v >>> 40);
    writeBuffer[3] = (byte)(v >>> 32);
    writeBuffer[4] = (byte)(v >>> 24);
    writeBuffer[5] = (byte)(v >>> 16);
    writeBuffer[6] = (byte)(v >>>  8);
    writeBuffer[7] = (byte)(v >>>  0);
    out.write(writeBuffer, 0, 8);
incCount(8);
}
```

Here are modifications for your case

```
public final byte[] longToBytes(long v) {
    byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[ 8 ];

    writeBuffer[0] = (byte)(v >>> 56);
    writeBuffer[1] = (byte)(v >>> 48);
    writeBuffer[2] = (byte)(v >>> 40);
    writeBuffer[3] = (byte)(v >>> 32);
    writeBuffer[4] = (byte)(v >>> 24);
    writeBuffer[5] = (byte)(v >>> 16);
    writeBuffer[6] = (byte)(v >>>  8);
    writeBuffer[7] = (byte)(v >>>  0);

    return writeBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Are you unrolling the loop because it's more efficient?  Would the HotSpot compiler just do it for you?

Comment: Er, sorry, I suppose you didn't make that choice, you're just going with what writeLong() did.

Answer (score 5):

I would write the long to a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) wrapped in a [DataOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and then retrieve the raw bytes, although this will always give you your data in big endian byte order (most significant byte first):

```
public static byte[] getBytes(Long val)
    throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    dos.writeLong(val);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

If you want to be able to specify the endianness, you can use the [ByteBuffer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class:

```
public static byte[] getBytes(Long val)
{
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    buf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    buf.putLong(val);
    return buf.array();
}
```

Comment: Do you know how allocating a ByteBuffer compares with just allocating the byte[] directly?  I would be inclined to use byte[]-only solution because it seems cheaper.

Comment: I suppose I'll need to find the endianness of Cassandra.

Comment: @dfrankow: ByteBuffer is written in C++ and thus is probably designed for efficiency.  However, my advice is to not worry about these kinds of micro-optimizations until you've profiled your code and know for sure where the inefficiencies are.  Programmers are surprisingly bad at guessing where the slow spots in their code will be :)

Answer (score 2):

You can crack the bytes apart by using shifts and mask, or a bit easier is `ByteBuffer.wrap` to wrap an 8 long byte array and using the `putLong` method. You must set the ByteOrder first using the `ByteBuffer.order` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cassandra's utility class: `ByteBufferUtil.bytes(long n)`