# Android sending file name via socket communication

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-networking

I am able to send Files through socket and receive on other ends . Now i want to send even file name so that after receiving file and saving file from socket i can save the name of file. What to add in client to send filename and in server to receive filename thanks in advance to all

Client.java

```
try {

                clientSocket = new Socket(targetIP, port);
                os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);


                InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                signalActivity("About to start handshake");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToSend);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                // long BytesToSend = fileToSend.length();

                while(true)
                {

                    int bytesRead = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    if(bytesRead == -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    //BytesToSend = BytesToSend - bytesRead;
                    os.write(buffer,0, bytesRead);
                    os.flush();
                }
                fis.close();
                bis.close();

                br.close();
                isr.close();
                is.close();

                pw.close();
                os.close();

                clientSocket.close();


            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
```

Server.java

```
try {



            welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            while(true && serviceEnabled)
            {

                socket = welcomeSocket.accept();

                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);


                String inputData = "";

//              String savedAs = "WDFL_File_" + System.currentTimeMillis();

//save the original name and extention

                File file = new File(saveLocation, savedAs);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                while(true)
                {
                    bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    if(bytesRead == -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bos.flush();

                }

                bos.close();
                socket.close();
                //Start writing to file

            }


        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: @Bhargav where i didn't get u

Comment: @Bhargav no from one device to another

Comment: no yea you are indeed receiving the file on your server `File file = new File(saveLocation, savedAs);` so you used to saveAs some random file name?

Comment: @Bhargav i know i am saving random text but i want to save as actual text with extention

Comment: and I think this answer should be your solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/15650962/4128945

Comment: @Bhargav it did not work friend

Comment: @Payal Define 'did not work'. It looks OK to me.

Comment: NB Don't flush inside a loop.

Comment: @EJP can you give me working example its not working

Answer (score 0):

Your client should send the file name first. After that the contents of the file.

The server should read the file name first so the following content of the file can be saved under the same file name.