# Java parsing long from string

Tags: java, string, parsing

I'm currently trying to parse some long values stored as Strings in java, the problem I have is this:

```
String test = "fffff8000261e000"
long number = Long.parseLong(test, 16);
```

This throws a NumberFormatException:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fffff8000261e000"
```

However, if I knock the first 'f' off the string, it parses it fine.

I'm guessing this is because the number is large and what I'd normally do is put an 'L' on the end of the long to fix that problem.  I can't however work out the best way of doing that when parsing a long from a string.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks

Comment: please note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java

Comment: Check out `BigDecimal`, it should be able to handle large, precise numbers no problem. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: If, as you correctly spot, the number is too large you won't be able to parse a long. You'll need a numeric type with a higher capacity. As @wemu points out, try parsing it into a `BigInteger`. If you still need a `long` try using `BigInteger#longValue()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two different ways of answering your question, depending on exactly what sort of behavior you're really looking for.

Answer #1:  As other people have pointed out, your string (interpreted as a *positive* hexadecimal integer) is too big for the Java `long` type.  So if you really need (positive) integers that big, then you'll need to use a different type, perhaps `java.math.BigInteger`, which also has a constructor taking a `String` and a radix.

Answer #2: I wonder, though, if your string represents the "raw" bytes of the `long`.  In your example it would represent a negative number.  If that's the case, then Java's built-in `long` parser doesn't handle values where the high bit is set (i.e. where the first digit of a 16 digit string is greater than 7).

If you're in case #2, then here is one (pretty inefficient) way of handling it:

```
String test = "fffff8000261e000";
long number = new java.math.BigInteger(test, 16).longValue();
```

which produces the value `-8796053053440`.  (If your string is more than 16 hex digits long, it would silently drop any higher bits.)

If efficiency is a concern, you could write your own bit-twiddling routine that takes the hex digits off the end of the string two at a time, perhaps building a byte array, then converting to long.  Some similar code is here:

[How to convert a Java Long to byte[] for Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641150/how-to-convert-a-java-long-to-byte-for-cassandra)

Answer (score 1):

The number you are parsing is too large to fit in a java Long. Adding an `L` wouldn't help. If Long had been an unsigned data type, it would have fit.

One way to cope is to divide the string in two parts and then use bit shift when adding them together:

```
String s= "fffff8000261e000";
long number;
long n1, n2;

if (s.length() < 16) {
    number = Long.parseLong(s, 16);
}
else {
    String s1 = s.substring(0, 1);
    String s2 = s.substring(1, s.length());

    n1=Long.parseLong(s1, 16) << (4 * s2.length());
    n2= Long.parseLong(s2, 16);

    number = (Long.parseLong(s1, 16) << (4 * s2.length())) + Long.parseLong(s2, 16);
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString(n1));
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString(n2));
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString(number));
}
```

Note:

If the number is bigger than Long.MAX_VALUE the resulting `long` will be a negative value, but the bit pattern will match the input.

Comment: My test shows that Long.toHexString(number) is f00000000000000.

Comment: @Ziyao Wei  There was a bug in my code (the assignment of `s2` was off by one). The updated code is tested and it works. Thanks for pointing out that there was a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The primitive [long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) variable can hold values in the range from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to  `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` inclusive.

The calculation shows that `fffff8000261e000` hexademical is `18,446,735,277,656,498,176` decimal, which is obviously out of bounds. Instead, `fffff8000261e000` hexademical is `1,152,912,708,553,793,536` decimal, which is as obviously within bounds.

As everybody here proposed, use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to account for such cases. For example, `BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("fffff8000261e000", 16);` will solve your problem. Also, `new java.math.BigInteger("fffff8000261e000", 16).toString()` will yield `18446735277656498176` exactly.

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't answer the question. This fits as a comment instead unless you propose a solution.