# Reverse bytes order of long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I've got a `long` variable and I need to reverse its byte order. For example: `B1, B2, ... , B8` I should return a long that consists of `B8, B7, ..., B1`. How can I do it by using bitwise operations?

Comment: Are you working with endian-ness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [Long.reverseBytes(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#reverseBytes%28long%29)

Or for more methods which include bitwise operations, you can refer to this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586882/how-do-i-convert-a-byte-to-a-long-in-java/1586920#1586920)

Heres another method you may like, I'd still recommend the above but it's better than bitwise where you can easily make mistakes.

[Bytebuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(someLong).array();
for (int left = 0, right = bytes.length - 1; left < right; ++left, --right) {
    byte temp = bytes[left]; 
    bytes[left]  = bytes[right]; 
    bytes[right] = temp;
}
```

I am trying to steer you away from bitwise solutions because they are cumbersome and very easy to mess up if you do not know what you are doing... But bitwise would look like this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];

// set the byte array from smallest to largest byte
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    byte[i] = (your_long >> i*8) & 0xFF;
}

// build the new long from largest to smallest byte (reversed)
long l = ((buf[0] & 0xFFL) << 56) |
         ((buf[1] & 0xFFL) << 48) |
         ((buf[2] & 0xFFL) << 40) |
         ((buf[3] & 0xFFL) << 32) |
         ((buf[4] & 0xFFL) << 24) |
         ((buf[5] & 0xFFL) << 16) |
         ((buf[6] & 0xFFL) <<  8) |
         ((buf[7] & 0xFFL) <<  0) ;
```

Comment: The `Arrays.asList(bytes)` code won't work -- `Arrays.asList(bytes)` will return a `List<byte[]>`, not a `List<Byte>` -- it'll return a list with one element, the whole byte array.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Interesting, I saw the snippet pop up a few times on different websites so assumed it was correct, but you are right it is not, I'll replace it.

Comment: @Serdalis Your solution with the `ByteBuffer` works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `Long.reverseBytes` instead of using bitwise operations. See the [Java Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#reverseBytes%28long%29) for details.

Otherwise, you could have a look at the JDK sources (src.zip in your JDK folder) in `Long.java` but mind the copyright by Oracle.

Comment: And what if I cannot use `Long.reverseBytes` and need to do it with bitwise operations?

Comment: @BenM Added a pointer to the JDK sources in my answer. In `Long.reverseBytes` it is done with bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an old trick that you can use to endian swap a register:

```
static long swapblock(long a, long mask, int shift) {
    long b1 = a & mask; // extract block
    long b2 = a ^ b1;   // extract remaining bits
    return (b1 << shift) |
           ((b2 >> shift) & mask); // mask again to clear sign extension
}

static long endianswap(long a) {
    a = swapblock(a, 0x00000000ffffffffL, 32);
    a = swapblock(a, 0x0000ffff0000ffffL, 16);
    a = swapblock(a, 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL, 8);
    return a;
}
```

The idea is to progressively swap sub blocks until you reach the desired level you want to stop at. By adding swaps of sizes 4, 2, and 1, you can change this into a bit mirror function.

There is only one tricky bit due to lack of unsigned types in java. You need to mask out high order bits when shifting right, because the sign bit is replicated by the shift amount, filling the high order bits with ones (`0x8000000000000000 >> 8` is `0xFF80000000000000`).

Answer (score 0):

```
long reverse(long x){
     x = (x >> 32) | (x << 32); // step 1
     x = ((x & 0xffff0000ffff0000 ) >> 16) 
          | ((x & 0x0000ffff0000ffff ) << 16); // step 2
     x = ((x & 0xff00ff00ff00ff00 ) >> 8) 
          | ((x & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff ) << 8); // step 3
     return x;
}
```

If we assume that bitwise operator works in O(1) time, reverse function works in O(lg(number of bits) ) time.
Explanation
Step 0 : B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 
Step 1 : B5 B6 B7 B8 B1 B2 B3 B4
Step 2 : B7 B8 B5 B6 B3 B4 B1 B2
Step 3 : B8 B7 B6 B5 B4 B3 B2 B1

Answer (score 0):

Plain answer with loops:

```
public static long byteReverse(long a) {

    long result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        // grab the byte in the ith place
        long x = (a >> (i*8)) & (0b11111111);
        result <<= 8;
        result |= x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

bitwise only:

```
public static long byteReverse(long a) {

    a = (a << 32) | (a >>> 32);
    a = ((a & 0xffff0000ffff0000L) >>> 16) | ((a & 0x0000ffff0000ffffL) << 16);
    a = ((a & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL) << 8) | ((a & 0xff00ff00ff00ff00L) >>> 8);

    return a;
}
```