# Merge two bytes in java/android

Tags: android, byte, multibyte

I have a frame of 22 bytes. The frame is the input stream from an accelerometer via bluetooth. The acceleromter readings are a 16 bit number split over two bytes.

When i try to merge the bytes with buffer[1] + buffer[2], rather than adding the bytes, it just puts the results side by side. so 1+2 = 12.

Could someone tell me how to combine these two bytes to obtain the original number. (btw the bytes are sent little endian)

Thanks

Comment: Look into bitwise and bit-shift operations. http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/bitops.html

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026761/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-its-numeric-value-java

Answer (score 27, accepted):

here's the code:

```
public static short twoBytesToShort(byte b1, byte b2) {
          return (short) ((b1 << 8) | (b2 & 0xFF));
}
```

Comment: Thats great, Thanks a million

Comment: @Shane, if this works for you, you should 'Accept' the answer :)

Comment: Why are you OR'ing the bottom byte by 0xFF?

Comment: The &OxFF is a must!!! This is due to the fact that some Java architectures do integer promotions so if 'b2' > 127 the result will have a negative sign (highest bit of 'b2' became the sign bit since it was promoted to 32'th bit of integer). I have personally seen this happening On Android 6 devices

Answer (score -1):

Here's a better answer that might make a little more sense...

```
public static short twoBytesToShort(byte b1, byte b2) {
          return (short) ((b1 << 8) | b2);
}
```

(b2 & 0xFF) comes out with the same exact binary pattern.

Comment: That is completely wrong and might yield wrong result. The &OxFF is a must!!! This is due to the fact that some Java architectures do integer promotions so if 'b2' > 127 the result will have a negative sign (highest bit of 'b2' became the sign bit since it was promoted to 32'th bit of integer). I have personally seen this happening (On Android 6 devices)