# Why no readUnsignedInt in RandomAccessFile class?

Tags: java

I just found there is no `readUnsignedInt`() method in the `RandomAccessFile` class. Why? Is there any workaround to read an unsigned int out from the file?

**Edit:**

I want to read an unsigned int from file and put it into a long space.

**Edit2:**

Cannot use readLong(). it will read 8 bytes not 4 bytes. the data in the file have unsigned ints in 4 bytes range.

**Edit3:**

Found answer here: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/183.cfm

**Edit4:**

how about if the data file is little-endian? we need to bits swap first?

Comment: Java doesn't support unsigned integers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints

Comment: @Swati: Well, they could've done it like with `readUnsignedShort()` which reads 2 bytes and returns an int: Read 4 bytes and return a long.

Comment: They could've also just implemented unsigned int, but what can you do.

Comment: Pete freitag's answer is rather long winded. There are any number of sorter, simpler solutions available in the JDK itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
long l = file.readInt() & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
```

The bit operation is necessary because the upcast will extend a negative sign.

---

Concerning the endianness. To the best of my knowledge all I/O in Java is done in big endian fashion. Of course, often it doesn't matter (byte arrays, UTF-8 encoding, etc. are not affected by endianness) but many methods of `DataInput` are. If your number is stored in little endian, you have to convert it yourself. The only facility in standard Java I know of that allows configuration of endianness is `ByteBuffer` via the `order()` method but then you open the gate to NIO and I don't have a lot of experience with that.

Comment: Yes, it is better solution :)

Comment: Kindly notice that without the "L" at the end of the 0xFFFFFFFF this solution will not work, without the L if your number is negative your long will be negative too

Answer (score 3):

Edited to remove `readLong()`:

You could use `readFully(byte[] b, int off, int len)` and then convert to `Long` with the methods here: [How to convert a byte array to its numeric value (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026761/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-its-numeric-value-java)

Comment: This won't help if the number in the file is 4 bytes long. `readLong()` reads 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no unsigned int type in java?
Why not `readLong()` ?
You can readLong and then take first 32 bits.

**Edit**
You can try

```
long value = Long.parseLong(Integer.toHexString(file.readInt()), 16);
```

Comment: *Because there is no unsigned int type in java?* Well, there is actually a `readUnsignedByte`...

Comment: And then use `seek()` to go 4 bytes back because `readLong()` consumes too many bytes?

Comment: @aioobe, yes, sorry, didn't notice these methods.

Comment: Nothing personal, I think both solutions are horrible. The first consumes too many bytes, the second creates a hex string and parses it?! Java is not a scripting language. Why does this answer have so many upvotes?

Comment: @musiKk, it depends on how you measure 'beaty' of the code. If you need speed - yes, my solution is horrible. But if you don't care adout speed much, it is smaller solution than create long from array of bytes. Although I understand that if somebody use RandomAccessFile, he is likely need speed.

Comment: @Nikita: Ok, I think I got a little carried away. Still, I think creating a temporary string that only gets parsed again should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing with the `int`, you may not need to turn it into a long.  You just need to be aware of the operations you are performing.  After all its just 32-bits and you can treat it as signed or unsigned as you wish.

If you want to play with the ByteOrder, the simplest thing to do may be to use ByteBuffer which allows you to set a byte order. If your file is less than 2 GB, you can map the entire file into memory and access the ByteBuffer randomly.