# Using Lucene API to show float field from Solr index

Tags: api, solr, lucene, floating-point

I've inherited some code which uses the Lucene API to query a Solr index.

The code does a lot of searches, and at the end converts all found lucene documents to solr documents:

```
// doc:Document

val sdoc = new SolrDocument

for (f:Fieldable <- doc.getFields if f.isStored) {
  sdoc.addField(f.name(),f.stringValue())
}
```

This works fine, except for when the field value isn't a string, e.g. floats or booleans. On float fields, `stringValue()` returns some weird characters (e.g. ¿£൱), presumably the string representation of a float.

How do I properly get the float value from a Lucene document?

Comment: how are you storing floats? which version of lucene are you using? Do you see the correct value when inspected using Luke?

Answer (score 3):

For Numeric stored as binary value, you need to get by *doc.getBinaryValue(fieldName)* you will get **byte[]** as return value which you will have to convert it into your appropriate numeric value. This is what you could do:

```java
if(!field.isBinary()){
    sdoc.addField(fieldName, doc.get(fieldName));
} else{
    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(doc.getBinaryValue(fieldName));
    sdoc.addField(fieldName, buff.getFloat());
}
```

Here's a [SO Quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026761/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-its-numeric-value-java) that provides help with the conversion.

Comment: what if the field is a sdouble (SortableDouble)? the code runs to the not a binary field block for sdouble, as a result, i got a weird string like " @#sV7&"...thanks for your help!

Comment: NumberUtils.SortableStr2doubleStr(indexedForm);