# comparing byte arrays

Tags: java, compare, arrays

I have two byte-arrays (in Java) representing two (possibly negative) numbers.

How do I compare them (ie., finding out which one is smaller/greater)?

Currently, I just compare them by resurrecting them into two java's `int` and then doing the comparison. But that'd give the wrong result in cases where one of the byte-array represents a negative number and the other positive.It's impossible to tell whether the left-most bit is the sign or just part of the number, right?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026761/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-its-numeric-value-java - look it up over here.

Comment: Are your bytes ordered from most significant to least or the other way? If from most to least: Isn't the left-most bit the sign in the first byte and just part of the number in all following bytes? Do you have a constant number of bytes, or do they vary?

Comment: If they're both guaranteed to be 4 bytes, the leftmost bit is always the sign bit.

Answer (score 3):

Why reinvent the wheel? Use ByteBuffer:

```
int a = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArrayA).getInt();
int b = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArrayB).getInt();
System.out.println(a == b);
```

Comment: You can specify order with ByteBuffer. order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)