# How to use Wrap Method of ByteBuffer in Java

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, byte, bytebuffer

Okay, so I was looking up what the best way to convert from a byte array to it's numeric value in java was and I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026761/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-its-numeric-value-java). And the second answer mentions the use of the ByteBuffer class. For those that do not wish to click on the link, originally the question asks if I have:

```
byte[] by = new byte[8];
```

How does one convert that to int? Well the answer goes...

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4});
long l = bb.getLong();

System.out.println(l);
```

Result

```
4
```

And that is awesome to learn, but I just want to confirm something before going that route.

Say I have a previously read in byte array that is 8 bytes long.

```
byte[] oldByte = new byte[8];
```

then I do...

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {oldByte[2], oldByte[3]});
int intValue = bb.getInt();
```

Will that work/be read in the same manner as the previous example?

Comment: You will get a java.nio.BufferUnderflowException because you need 4 bytes to have an int, but you are only giving the ByteBuffer 2 bytes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt%28%29) for the `ByteBuffer` class specifies that the `getInt()` method reads the next *four* bytes, so if you are only passing two bytes to the call to `wrap`, you will get a  `BufferUnderflowException`:

> Throws: BufferUnderflowException - If there are fewer than four bytes remaining in this buffer

Comment: So you are saying it should be: `ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {0, 0, oldByte[2], oldByte[3]});`?

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer Yes, according to the docs the default byte order is big endian, so that looks right.