# Apache POI HMEF - How to get attachment size from MS TNEF message?

Tags: java, apache-poi, tnef

I have a `HMEFMessage` and iterating all attachments using

```
for (Attachment tnefAttachment : hmef.getAttachments()) {
```

Attachment size can be obtained using `tnefAttachment.getMAPIAttribute(MAPIProperty.ATTACH_SIZE)` . This method returns MAPIAttribute instance and it has only getData(), which returns byte[].

How can I convert byte[] from MAPIAttribute to Long (size)?

According to this - https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hmef/attribute/package-summary.html - there is a MAPIStringAttribute.getAsString(attr), which does not work with ATTACH_SIZE.

EDIT - ATTACH_SIZE is Long according to http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.openl.rules/org.openl.lib.poi.dev/5.9.4.1/org/apache/poi/hsmf/datatypes/MAPIProperty.java .

Answer (score 2):

`MAPIProperty.ATTACH_SIZE` only indicates the attribute you are requesting with `getMAPIAttribute()` so its type does not matter.

I suggest using the size of the content to solve your problem:

```
tnefAttachment.getContent().length
```

will give you the size of the attachment in bytes.

If you want to convert a byte array to long, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026761/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-its-numeric-value-java).

Comment: Yeah, but calling getContent() downloads a file from server, doesn't it? I wanted to get a size without fetching a file actually.

Comment: HSMF works on files anyways. If you do not want to use that approach, convert the bytes to a single long as in the linked question.